# Trying to add php to a list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of list items, on the left side and aligned vertically. I'm trying to make so that the container on the right side, which is empty, will populate with information from the url for that list item's specific id. Currently, I've created a jQuery function using `load()` and it allows me to click within the list item and data is populated in the right container, but it's only the data for the smallest id. If I click the other list items, the data in the right container doesn't change.

I tried adding a link within the list item, and it works. The correct data is shown, however, I leave my current page every time to see it and it doesn't populate in the container on the right at all, which is now on the previous page.

Is there anyway to get the proper id assigned to the proper list item?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
    $("#divId").load("pm_message.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>&pmid=<?php echo $pmid; ?> #pm_post");
    });
    });
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper"> <!--Left and Right container wrapper-->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <!--left container-->
      <div class="top">
        <input type="text" />
        <a href="javascript:;" class="search"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="people">
        <a href="pm_message.php?u=<?php echo $log_username; ?>&pmid=<?php echo $pmid; ?>"><?php echo $people; ?></a> <!--generates list of people-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right">
      <!--Right container-->
      <div class="top"><span class="name"></span></div>
      <div id="divId"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And script:

```
    //DB connection
    //Collecting data from db
    //Variable $people collects data for the people listed in the left container
    $people = '
                <li class="person">
                  <a id="a" href="pm_message.php?u='.$log_username.'&pmid='.$pmid.'"><span class="name">'.$sender.'</span></a>
                            <!--<span class="name">'.$sender.'</span>-->
                            <span class="time">'.$time.'</span>
                            <span class="preview">'.$message.'</span>
                </li>';
```

Comment: Maybe you have to change the selector *#divId* to *#convo*?

Answer (score 0):

You are always sending the same url reuqest:

You should take url dynamically depends on `li`clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").click(function() {

        var strReqUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#divId").load(strReqUrl);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't work. Now nothing appears on the right side container.